# Removing a specific element depending on the URL with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tumblr

I've searched all over the internet for an answer and there seems to be bits and pieces that when I try to assemble don't work. The main problem is that I am trying to make an element show on one page. The problem is that the platform (Tumblr) does not allow you to edit other pages directly (the '/tagged/' pages) so this element, the carousel, is present on every page. The solution I thought of was to use jquery to remove the element depending on the url but this is not working.

I am a novice to programming so while I do know the basics, I'm missing the experience to put this into effect.

```
if (document.location.pathname == '/tagged/') {
}
else { function showOne(id) {
$('.hide').not('#' + id).hide();
}
showOne(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try below code:

```
if (document.location.pathname.indexOf("/tagged/") >= 0) {
}
else { 
    function showOne(id) {
         $('.hide').not('#' + id).hide();
    }
    showOne(1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with contains jQuery selector:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
if($( "a[href*='tagged']" )) {
    alert('ci sono');
 function showOne(id) {
         $('.hide').not('#' + id).hide();
    }
    showOne(1);
}
});
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/UxHkZ/

Enjoy your code!